# Get just audio section of FLAC

Tags: audio, metadata, flac

I've written a script to "normalize" all my FLAC files by stripping unneeded tags, padding tracknumber/discnumber, removing pictures, etc. As part of the normalization process, my script re-compresses the FLAC file to level 8. Since re-compressing an already level-8 FLAC is pointless and time consuming, I want a way to know if the audio of the FLAC file has been changed since my last compression (I don't want to use file modification time because changing the metadata would change this as well). Is there an easy way to get the MD5 hash or something of the FLAC audio section so I can quickly check if it's been altered? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the python-audio-tools over at http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/. Here's the relevant code, for future reference:

```
track = audiotools.open('file.flac')
metadata = track.get_metadata()
raw_hash = metadata.get_block(audiotools.flac.Flac_STREAMINFO.BLOCK_ID).md5sum
print(audiotools.hex_string(raw_hash))
```